# Parameterising Docker Image prefix

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I have a Dockerfile which has the following content

```
# Build
FROM ${ECR_PREFIX}/maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

# Package
FROM ${ECR_PREFIX}/openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/application.jar application.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

I tried to build this using

```
export PREFIX=${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
docker build -t backend --build-arg ECR_PREFIX=$PREFIX .
```

but this would not work. I am really trying not to hard code the prefix especially **${AWS::AccountId}** part of it because of various reasons.

Any pointers here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly declare the `ARG` in your Dockerfile.  If you [use an `ARG` value in a `FROM` line](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) then the `ARG` needs to come before any `FROM`.  (Other `ARG`s need to be repeated in each build stage that uses them.)

```sh
ARG REGISTRY=docker.io
FROM ${REGISTRY}/maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 AS build
```

```sh
REGISTRY=${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com
docker build \
  -t $REGISTRY/backend:$(git rev-parse HEAD) \
  --build-arg REGISTRY=$REGISTRY \
  .
```